# Where inside viewDidLoad is the best place to use self.table.ReloadData()?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having the issue when building via TestFlight, but not via the simulator - Sometimes when I open the homepage, nothing happens until I scroll on the screen. That leads me to believe it might be better to reloadData somewhere else (somewhere simpler) so that this does not happen. Below is where I am reloading currently

///////PART A

```
 public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    
    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    
    
    
    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]
    
    let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    
    
    cell.lblName.text = person.Education
    
    cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID
    
    
    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        print(PhotoPosts, "sttdb")
        immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
        
        
    }
    
    
    return cell
    
    
    
}
```

//////Part B

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

        
    let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid 
    
    refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");
    
    refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: { [weak self]snapshot in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            
            self.people.removeAll()
            
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                

                if people.key != thisUsersUid {
                    print("peoplekey",people.key)

                    let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
                    .............

                    .............


                    if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) {
                        
                        .......

                        if self.array1.contains(people.key){
                            print(self.array1, "f111111")
                            
                            let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation........)
                            
                            self.people.append(peopl)
                            
                        } else {
                            print ("w")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print ("alpha")
                        
                    }
                    

                }
                
                self.people.sort { ($0.distance ?? 0) < ($1.distance ?? 0) }
                self.table.reloadData()


                
                print("aaaaaaaa", self.people.map {$0.distance})
                
                
            }

        }
        

        
    }
```

Comment: Obviously what you are showing, with `{ [weak self]snapshot in` in the middle of nowhere, is nonsense. Could you please show your real code? That would really help us to help you. Just copy and paste your actual code right into the question. Thanks!

Comment: I did copy and paste, but that line copy erroneously didn't start at the beginning. My bad. I fixed that now. The spaces where I put `....` also contain code, but that would make it unnecessarily long for you all to read.

Comment: Okay, well, if you are sure that that is your real code, you are calling `reloadData()` every time through the `for people in` loop, which is inefficient. You should be using DispatchGroup so that you call `reloadData()` once after all the iterations of the loop have finished. However, I still doubt that this is your real code. I appreciate the `....` but let's not make assumptions about what can be safely omitted from consideration.

Comment: is there any implementation code of your observer/observable design pattern. Your observer will start observing after the view is loaded, so there is i guess no initial `reloadData()` and thats why it's only working after any changes of the observable object. Even worse, when the observable object in use is the tableview itself, then scrolling or similar will trigger a reload.

Comment: @Ol Sen why is that definitely worse if periodic reloads are necessary for the functionality?  What instead of tableview should the observable object then be? There are overrides: `didSelectRowAt`, `heightForRowAt`, `numberOfRowsInSection`. They don't have `realodData()`

Comment: in tableviews usually you want to observe your data model for changes and make them visible to the user by invoking a reload which will according to the docs only "rebuild"  those cells that are in the visible range of the tableview. So your viewDidLoad will contain at least one reload at the very end to kick the build up and the observer will watch the datasource instead of the tableview. you dont want that any change in the whole table (like scrolling) would trigger a reload process every time a property causes the observable to invoke a notification to the observer.

Comment: The comment from @matt above is correct. You're refreshing the tableView inside the loop which will cause flicker and other issues. You're also sorting `self.people` within that loop as well over and over. Also, you've got a class var called `people` and then the loop item is called `people` and that's confusing. So, move the sort and then the tableView reload right *after* the loop. e.g. populate your dataSource within the loop, sort it and then refresh the UI to reflect those changes.

Comment: Also, be mindful of this `observe(DataEventType.value` as it tells firebase that if anything changes in the observed node, reload ALL of the data from that node, even the unchanged data. You may want to consider `.observeSingleEvent` or add discreet observers for .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved to provide a more granular level of control.

Comment: @Jay, thanks. For the sorting and reloading, how would you put them outside the loop? The furthest that it works is outside the `if snapshot.childrenCount>0` closure, but inside the `refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value` closure

Comment: Not sure how to answer that question. Put the lines of code directly following the loop so the loop completes before calling that code.  `for i in 0...9 { inside loop } code that executes after loop`. You want the loop to do its thing before attempting to access (sort) your dataSource or refreshing the tableView.